# If $B\subset A$ and the exist a injection $A\rightarrow B$, then $A$ and $B$ has same cardinality?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

By using the definition, the cardinality is the same iff there is a bijection. So if $B\subset A$ and the exist a injection $f\colon A\rightarrow B$, then $A$ and $B$ has same cardinality.

Comment: You can prove this without and prior to CBS Theorem. See http://math.ucsd.edu/~wgarner/reference/math109_wi08/bernstein_schroeder_theorem.pdf.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If $B \subset A$ then there exists an injection $g : B \to A$ defined in the natural way (identity). By existence of $g$ and the injection $f : A \to B,$ invoke [Cantor–Bernstein–Schroeder theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%E2%80%93Bernstein%E2%80%93Schroeder_theorem) then there exist a bijection $h : A \to B.$ Hence $A$ and $B$ has the same cardinality.

Comment: is it possible to prove with the definition ,the cardinality is the same iff there is a bijection

Comment: That's what I did. $B \subset A \implies $ existence of injection $g : A \to B.$ Existence of both $g : A \to B$ and $h : A \to B$ will give us bijection (by C-B-S theorem.) Once we have the bijection, we get the same cardinality statement proven.

Comment: @Mathematics It is not.  The problem only provides an injection, so you need to prove that that bijection exists.  The proof J.D. linked is necessary in order to do that.

Comment: @Mathematics: That's exactly what the Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein Theorem does. It proves that if there is an injection in each direction, then there is a bijection. And the result does not even require the Axiom of Choice.

Comment: is it A and B must be infinite set? If it is finite, it seems that there is a problem like $B\subset A$ but there is a injective function $f: A\rightarrow B$, so where does the element say $a_0$ where $a_0\in A$ but not $\in B$ maps to. If it maps $a_0$ to some element in B say $b_0$, of course we know there always exist another $a\in A$ s.t.$f(a)=b_0$ where a not equal to $a_0$ As injection mean 1 to 1, which mean as many element in A as B is mapped to B and left some element $\in A$ but not $\in B$.

Comment: @Mathematics in the finite case, you should use $B \subseteq A$ rather than proper $\subset$.

Answer (score 8):

Any attempt to prove this result without explicitly using the [Cantor–Bernstein–Schroeder Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%E2%80%93Bernstein%E2%80%93Schroeder_theorem) will, in effect, end up re-proving the aforementioned theorem.

Let us call your statement "**mini-CBS**": Whenever $B \subseteq A$ are sets such that there is an injection $f : A \to B$, then $\left| A \right| = \left| B \right|$.

We now prove the CBS Theorem from mini-CBS: Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are sets, and we have injections $f: X \to Y$ and $g : Y \to X$.  Consider the set $X^\prime = \{ g(y) : y \in Y \}$.  Clearly, $X^\prime \subseteq X$.  Note that $g$ is in fact a bijection between $Y$ and $X^\prime$, and so $\left| X^\prime \right| = \left| Y \right|$.  Consider now the composition $g \circ f : X \to X^\prime$.  Since $f$ and $g$ are both one-to-one, it follows that $g \circ f$ is also one-to-one.  By mini-CBS it follows that $\left| X^\prime \right| = \left| X \right|$, and therefore $\left| Y \right| = \left| X \right|$.

Comment: In the course I TA'd during the fall semester we prove the Cantor-Bernstein theorem by first proving this mini-theorem. I think this is the cleanest proof I know of the theorem (except of course the AC based one that just take the minimal well-ordering of $A$ and $B$ and show it is the same ordinal).

Comment: @Asaf: Yeah, it's a very nice reduction, and the proof is somewhat less cluttered than the "usual" Choice-less lemma beginning with $A^\prime \subseteq B \subseteq A$ with $\left| A^\prime \right| = \left| A \right|$.  (At least that is how I recall seeing it proved in virtually every place I have seen a proof.)

Comment: Now, there is a question, is it necessary for A and B to be infinite set?

Comment: you can refer what i ask in the comment to Andre

Comment: @Mathematics: The proof would not depend on whether the sets A and B are finite or infinite.  Of course, if $A$ is a _proper_ subset of $B$ and there is an injection $f : B \to A$, this means that $B$ is [Dedekind infinite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind-infinite_set).  Without the Axiom of Choice we can show that all Dedekind infinite sets are infinite (meaning not equinumerous with any $\{ 0, \ldots , n-1 \}$), but the Axiom of Choice is required to show the converse, that every infinite set is Dedekind infinite.

Answer (score 2):

Yes that's right. $B\subset A$ implies that $|B|\le |A|$. The injection forces $|A|\le|B|$. Therefore they have the same cardinality.

Comment: is it possible to prove with the definition ,the cardinality is the same iff there is a bijection

Comment: My answer does that without explicitly saying so. The fact that  $|B|\le|A|$ and $|A|\le |B|$ implies $|A|= |B|$ is just another way to state the CBS Theorem, and $|A| = |B|$  is just shorthand for "there is a bijection from $A$ to $B$ ".